# Migrate database with groovy script

Tags: mysql, database, groovy

I need to migrate a database to an entirely new schema using groovy scripts, and I'm not sure where to start. Some of the table migrations will be almost one-to-one, apart from the new implementation of UUID's I have to use for all of the primary keys. 
For other tables, the data will have to be split up, and in some cases certain fields will have to be parsed into individual columns in the new database.

I believe I can do these things individually, but like I said I'm not sure where to start. Any helpful pointers, examples, links or advice would be welcome.

As an example, say in the old schema there is a person table with columns for name, job, etc. and personal info including address. In the new schema however there is an address table, so we need to migrate the address parts of person to an address entry and the rest to a person entry and connect the two with a UUID, via id and address_id respectfully. How do I do that?

Comment: Could you be more specific about which parts of the problem you're struggling with. Unless the migration logic is very complex it seems like an SQL script would be an easier way to perform the migration

Comment: @Don - I added an example. If it is immensely easier to do in SQL rather than groovy I can do that instead.

Comment: Groovy =) Almost +1. LOL @ "Related" in the right sidebar: `groovy` is the primary tag?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you have to use Groovy to migrate?

Comment: @Emil - My boss asked me to do them in Groovy (I'm an intern), he's not the kind of guy you usually argue with, so... Groovy.

Comment: @Yottagray if I had an intern working for me, I'd be very impressed if he came up with good arguments for doing things a different way than I'd suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't very complex but tedious. My suggested way to attack this:

1. Create a very small database for your tests. [H2 is your friend](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html).
2. Write small tests for each migration you need to do. This makes sure that changes tomorrow won't break today's work.
3. Load the small database with test cases (where your migration didn't work). Write tests for that.

A test looks like so:

1. Make a connection to the test database (or to two test databases, one in the old and one in the new format).
2. Call the migration routine with the connection(s)
3. Dump the result to a string
4. Compare the string with what you expect

Start with the most simple migration that you can find and work your way up from there.

Comment: DbUnit could be useful for loading data into the test database

Comment: I appreciate your suggestions, I have gotten a start on it now and it feels much more manageable. Thanks.